SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)
Trying to download nltk packages using nltk.download() on MacOS in India.
Tried this
import nltk
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

nltk.download()

The code runs and opens the NLTK Downloader window but I get the error:
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

I have also run the install Certificates.command:
/Applications/Python\ 3.12/Install\ Certificates.command ; exit;

I don't know what to do now. Btw I am running the code on a Jupyter notebook on a virtual environment
